# Orthonormal basis and general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

I'm trying to transform a vector into spherical coordinates,
that is a have a vector $X^a$ in Minkowski metric sign $(-+++)$
$$ X^a = (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) $$
where $x_i = x_i(t,x,y,z)$ i.e. components of the vector are functions of the Cartesian coordinates.
Now I want to transform this vector into the spherical metric
$$ ds^2 = - dt^2 + dr^2 + r^2 (d\theta^2 + \sin(\theta)^2d\phi^2) $$

But now I get confused, what I wanted to do is define the relations
$$ x = r cos(\phi) sin(\theta),\; y = r cos(\phi) sin(\theta), \; z = r cos(\theta) $$
and transform to vector to spherical as
$$ {X^{a}}' = \frac{\partial {x^a}'}{\partial x^b} X^b$$
where ${x^a}' = (t,r,\phi,\theta), \; x^a = (t,x,y,z)$ and ${X^a}'$ denotes the vector in spherical coordinates.
But did I transform into the right metric or did I transfer into an metric with respects to orthonormal basis? And if I transfered into the orthogonal one how do I transform into the right metric?

Comment: I missed that, thank you